# Creating a changing Google doodle style header

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a `<div>` to appear for users at midnight at their location. So if a user in New York is on the site and it's September 4th for them they won't see it, but users in Australia will where it is past midnight on September 5th. It would also have to disappear at 23:59 for those in Australia.

Is there any way to do this through HTML/javascript? I am wondering how Google get their doodles to appear at midnight because this would be for a similar thing with my site header image. I am on a Blogger platform.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Added code which only works in FF and not in other browsers

```
<div class='header-inner'>
<script>
var today = new Date(),
d = today.getDate(),
m = today.getMonth() + 1,
y = today.getFullYear(),
date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
specialDate = '5/9/2012';

if (date == specialDate) {
document.write(<div style='text-align:center; width:968px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:relative; top:-0px; z-index:3;'>
<img alt='' border='0' height='258' id='Image-Maps_9201209030919307' src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7EbtRf3eD6k/UBfBJKNkG8I/AAAAAAAABww/FDr_YNqs6zM/s1600/freddieforadayheader.png' usemap='#Image-Maps_9201209030919307' width='968'/>
<map id='_Image-Maps_9201209030919307' name='Image-Maps_9201209030919307'>
<area alt='' coords='5,212,44,252' href='http://twitter.com/#!/freddieforaday' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='51,213,90,253' href='http://www.facebook.com/FreddieForADay' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='98,212,137,252' href='http://www.youtube.com/user/FreddieForADay' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='238,206,724,246' href='http://www.freddieforaday.com/' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='777,151,963,253' href='http://www.freddieforaday.com/' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='166,79,797,151' href='http://www.freedomrequireswings.com/' shape='rect' title=''/>
</map>
</div>); 
document.write('<style>#header {display:none;}</style>'); 
}
</script>
<div class='header section' id='header'><div class='widget Header' id='Header1'>
<div id='header-inner'>
<div class='titlewrapper'>
<h1 class='title'>
<img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wlqM17mmGtI/UCwqdvlhrzI/AAAAAAAAB64/VUcGl3kFcxE/s1600/title.png' style='margin-bottom:-20px; padding-top:20px'/>
</h1>
</div>
<div class='descriptionwrapper'>
<p class='description'>
<span>
</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

What I have:

```
<div class='header-inner'>
<div class='header section' id='header'><div class='widget Header' id='Header1'>
<div id='header-inner'>
<div class='titlewrapper'>
<h1 class='title'>
<img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wlqM17mmGtI/UCwqdvlhrzI/AAAAAAAAB64/VUcGl3kFcxE/s1600/title.png' style='margin-bottom:-20px; padding-top:20px'/>
</h1>
</div>
<div class='descriptionwrapper'>
<p class='description'>
<span>
</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

What I want to end up with:

```
    <div class='header-inner'>
<div style='text-align:center; width:968px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;'>
<img alt='' border='0' height='258' id='Image-Maps_9201209030919307' src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7EbtRf3eD6k/UBfBJKNkG8I/AAAAAAAABww/FDr_YNqs6zM/s1600/freddieforadayheader.png' usemap='#Image-Maps_9201209030919307' width='968'/>
<map id='_Image-Maps_9201209030919307' name='Image-Maps_9201209030919307'>
<area alt='' coords='5,212,44,252' href='http://twitter.com/#!/freddieforaday' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='51,213,90,253' href='http://www.facebook.com/FreddieForADay' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='98,212,137,252' href='http://www.youtube.com/user/FreddieForADay' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='238,206,724,246' href='http://www.freddieforaday.com/' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='777,151,963,253' href='http://www.freddieforaday.com/' shape='rect' title=''/>
<area alt='' coords='166,79,797,151' href='http://www.freedomrequireswings.com/' shape='rect' title=''/>
</map>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I opted for...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var today = new Date(),
d = today.getDate(),
m = today.getMonth() + 1,
y = today.getFullYear(),
date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
specialDate = '5/9/2012';

if (date == specialDate) {
document.getElementById("doodle").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("defaultheader").style.display = "none";
} 
else {
document.getElementById("doodle").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("defaultheader").style.display = "block";
} 
</script>
```

I then put my custom doodle code inside

```
<div id='doodle'>
```

and my default everyday header inside

```
<div id='defaultheader'>
```

It works in all browsers and is simple to customize.

Big thanks to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) for all his help!

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be:

```
var today = new Date(),
    d = today.getDate(),
    m = today.getMonth() + 1,
    y = today.getFullYear(),
    date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
    specialDate = '4/9/2012';

if (date == specialDate) {
    console.log('yay!'); /* or whatever */
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lw5yJ/).

Showing how to add an `img` to the `body`:

```
var today = new Date(),
    d = today.getDate(),
    m = today.getMonth() + 1,
    y = today.getFullYear(),
    date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
    specialDate = '4/9/2012',
    specialImage = document.createElement('img');
specialImage.src = 'http://www.eventspianist.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/special_occasion.jpg';

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(specialImage);

if (date == specialDate) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(specialImage);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lw5yJ/1/).

**Edited** based on further information provided in comments (by the OP), the following simply changes the `src` attribute of the already-present image:

```
var today = new Date(),
    d = today.getDate(),
    m = today.getMonth() + 1,
    y = today.getFullYear(),
    date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
    imgToReplace = document.getElementById('header-inner'),
    specialDate = '4/9/2012',
    specialImageSrc = 'http://www.eventspianist.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/special_occasion.jpg';

console.log(imgToReplace);

if (date == specialDate) {
    imgToReplace.src = 'http://www.eventspianist.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/special_occasion.jpg';
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lw5yJ/2/).

This version explicitly replaces the old image with the newly-created image:

```
var today = new Date(),
    d = today.getDate(),
    m = today.getMonth() + 1,
    y = today.getFullYear(),
    date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
    imgToReplace = document.getElementById('header-inner'),
    specialDate = '4/9/2012',
    specialImage = document.createElement('img');
specialImage.src = 'http://www.eventspianist.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/special_occasion.jpg';

if (date == specialDate) {
    imgToReplace.parentNode.replaceChild(specialImage, imgToReplace);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lw5yJ/3/).

**Edited** to, hopefully, achieve the requirements added since the question was asked:

```
function createArea(parent, coords, href, shape) {
    if (!parent || !coords || !href) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var newArea = document.createElement('area'),
            shape = shape || 'rect';
        newArea.coords = coords;
        newArea.href = href;
        newArea.shape = shape;

        parent.appendChild(newArea);

        return newArea;
    }
}

var today = new Date(),
    d = today.getDate(),
    m = today.getMonth() + 1,
    y = today.getFullYear(),
    date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
    specialDate = '5/9/2012',
    headerInner = document.getElementsByClassName('header-inner')[0],
    childDiv = document.createElement('div'),
    newImg = document.createElement('img'),
    newMap = document.createElement('map');

if (date == specialDate) {

    // setting up attributes of the newImg:
    newImg.id = 'Image-Maps_9201209030919307';
    newImg.src = 'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7EbtRf3eD6k/UBfBJKNkG8I/AAAAAAAABww/FDr_YNqs6zM/s1600/freddieforadayheader.png';
    newImg.setAttribute('usemap', '#Image-Maps_9201209030919307');
    newImg.style.height = '258px';
    newImg.style.width = '968px';
    newImg.style.borderWidth = '0';

    childDiv.appendChild(newImg);

    // Setting up the imagemap:
    newMap.id = 'Image-Maps_9201209030919307';
    newMap.name = newMap.id;

    childDiv.insertBefore(newMap, newImg.nextSibling);

    // setting up the areas:
    var area1 = createArea(newMap, '51,213,90,253', 'http://www.facebook.com/FreddieForADay'),
        area2 = createArea(newMap, '98,212,137,252', 'http://www.youtube.com/user/FreddieForADay'),
        area3 = createArea(newMap, '238,206,724,246', 'http://www.freddieforaday.com/'),
        area4 = createArea(newMap, '777,151,963,253', 'http://www.freddieforaday.com/'),
        area5 = createArea(newMap, '166,79,797,151', 'http://www.freedomrequireswings.com/');

    console.log(area4);

    // emptying the headerInner div element:
    while (headerInner.firstChild) {
        headerInner.removeChild(headerInner.firstChild);
    }

    // adding the new content (all contained within the childDiv node):
    headerInner.appendChild(childDiv);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jVBSu/2/).

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm looking for, but it would have to replace the existing header on my page.

Comment: And how would your header image be uniquely identified? What's its `id`?

Comment: The contents of <div class='region-inner header-inner'> would have to change.

Comment: Add your code to the question; and then clearly, and specifically, explain, or *show* how your header image is uniquely identified.

Comment: Sorry, I've just understood. The header image is defined as #header-inner.

Comment: Hey it's ok! I managed to work it out. Thank you so much! I'll use this very often.

Comment: Turns out it only works in Firefox, not IE or webkit browsers. Any solutions? I've attached my code in the question.

Comment: No; it definitely works in Webkit (since I put it together in Chromium), Firefox 15 and Opera 12. Is it the demos that don't work, or is it the code you adapted it to suit in your project?

Comment: The code I adapted doesn't seem to work. I've added it in my question if you'd like to take a look?

Comment: Please could you use real elements from the *rendered* HTML ('view souce') instead of whatever server-side script that is?

Comment: And when that works, what HTML do you want to end up with? I need to see the 'before' HTML you *have* and the 'after' HTML that you *want*.  Just the HTML (both before and after). And then I'll try and make it work.

Comment: Ok. The before is everything inside `<div class='header section' id='header'>` and the after is everything I've put in the code you gave me which is just above that in the attachment in my question. What I've done with the code in FF is, I've hidden `#header` when my code appears and made the JS code appear with `position:relative` above where `#header` is now hidden.

Comment: No. I want to see, literally, the HTML you want to end up with. And the starting HTML. I don't want to parse the JavaScript to try and interpret what you want, I want to *see* actual HTML that you want to end up with. Given that your JavaScript doesn't work (except in Firefox) I don't see the benefit in trying to make sense of it (sorry if that sounds harsh, but it'll take far too long that way).

Comment: Sorry, I've added what I have and what I want to end up with. Hope that's clearer. Thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: The last edit certainly works in Chromium and Firefox 15, and should, I think, work in the others; IE I can't test (since I don't have Windows), Opera is having issues with the image map not being applied (though I don't know why, and it's late enough that I'm going to bed regardless. I'll take a look tomorrow to try and figure that out).

Comment: Now works in Opera too; apparently the `#` *is* required in the `usemap` attribute, who knew? ... *ahem* ...

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate all of this, but isn't there a simpler way to do it by getting the JS to hide `header-inner` and just paste the HTML and CSS of the doodle into `document.write()`? It's just that I wanted to re-use the code in the future and since I have zero knowledge of Javascript, this code isn't that useful in my case I'm afraid. I'm sorry. I really hope I'm not being a pain. My code works perfectly in FF, but it's not changing anything in webkits or IE. If you want to see what I mean [here](http://www.freedomrequireswings.com/) is my site at the moment. See it in webkit and FF.

Comment: Yes, you could do that; but it's a terrible practice to get into, html is not a string, and should not be treated as such. You may not know JavaScript, but it looks like you're going to have to learn. For what it's worth I'm more than happy to show good, cross-browser means of doing something, but I'm not going to show you deprecated ways of doing stuff. Even if it seems easier. Learn to use JavaScript properly. The repetitive parts can be abstracted out to a function, for the most part (such as the `createArea()` function). Remember your way didn't work, this way does. See the benefit?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be working when I put it in. Where should I put it? Before `header-inner`? I tried it there and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Ok, never mind. I managed to do it using something else. I've posted my answer. It's much simpler and works for all browsers. Thank you so much for your help, patience, and advice though. I got half my final code from you so thanks so much! :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var now = new Date()` to get current date and time, then compare to the date when you want to display the `<div>.`

Comment: Ok. So it is possible? I don't know any javascript at all. Could you show me the code please? That would really help!